# force directed graph - why pointers change size along with the link width

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have ran into a problem of pointers changing their size along with the link width. I wanted to be able to dynamically change link width based on number of connections between the nodes. This function seems to be working fine, but now my pointers also change size and shift away. I would like pointers to stay the same size and not shift. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Alexey_D3/xhx3L8jn/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v3.js"></script>



  <style type="text/css">

.link {
    stroke: #999;
    stroke-opacity: .6;
}
.node text {
  pointer-events: none;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

  </style>

<title>OnlineQ</title>

</head>

<body>
     <div id="container" class="container">
           <div id="sidebar" style="display: none;">
                <div class="item-group">
                    <label class="item-label">Filter</label>
                    <div id="filterContainer" class="filterContainer checkbox-interaction-group"></div>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div id="graphContainer" class="graphContainer">
  <script>
var links = 
[
{"source":"a0","target":"a0","s_portfolio":"a","t_portfolio":"a","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"APP"},
{"source":"a1","target":"a2","s_portfolio":"a","t_portfolio":"c","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"APP"},
{"source":"a1","target":"a2","s_portfolio":"a","t_portfolio":"c","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"APP"},
{"source":"a1","target":"a0","s_portfolio":"b","t_portfolio":"a","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"APP"},
{"source":"a2","target":"a3","s_portfolio":"c","t_portfolio":"d","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"DB"},
{"source":"a4","target":"a3","s_portfolio":"e","t_portfolio":"d","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"DB"},
{"source":"a4","target":"a3","s_portfolio":"e","t_portfolio":"d","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"DB"},
{"source":"a4","target":"a3","s_portfolio":"e","t_portfolio":"d","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"DB"},
{"source":"a4","target":"a3","s_portfolio":"e","t_portfolio":"d","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"DB"},
{"source":"a1","target":"a2","s_portfolio":"a","t_portfolio":"c","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"APP"}
];

//Constants for the SVG
var width = 600,
    height = 600;
    var counter = {};

    links.forEach(function(obj) {
        var key = JSON.stringify(obj);
        counter[key] = (counter[key] || 0) + 1
    });

    var finalArray = [];

    for (var key in counter) {
        var tempkey = key.substring(0, key.length - 1) + ",\"value\":" + counter[key] + "}";
        finalArray.push(tempkey)
    };

    finalArray.forEach(function(d, i, array) {
        array[i] = (JSON.parse(d))
    })

    console.log(finalArray);

var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
finalArray.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source, portfolio: link.s_portfolio, s_node_TYPE: link.SOURCE_TYPE});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target, portfolio: link.t_portfolio, t_node_TYPE: link.DES_TYPE});
});


//Set up the colour scale
var color = d3.scale.category20();

//Set up the force layout
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(200)
    .gravity(0.01);


//Append a SVG to the body of the html page. Assign this SVG as an object to svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var linkedByIndex = {};


//Creates the graph data structure out of the json data
force.nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(finalArray)
    .start();

//Create all the line svgs but without locations yet
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(finalArray)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
        if (d.value <2.5) { return 1}
        if (d.value >2.5 && d.value <3.5) { return 2}
        if (d.value >3.5) { return 3}
        })
     .style("marker-end",  function(d) {
            if (d.SOURCE_TYPE == "DB" || d.DES_TYPE =="DB" || d.source==d.target) {return ""}
            else    {return "url(#source)";}}) //Added ;

//Do the same with the circles for the nodes - no 
    console.log(links);
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", function (d) {
        if (d.type == "a") {
           return "BA node";
        } else {
           return "other node";
        }
    })
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout)
    .call(force.drag);

d3.selectAll(".BA").append("rect")
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
            if (d.class == "L") {return 0}
            if (d.class == "M") {return 1}
            else    {return 2}
    ;})
    .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.portfolio);    
});

d3.selectAll(".other").append("circle")
    .attr("r", 8)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
            if (d.class == "L") {return 0}
            if (d.class == "M") {return 1}
            else    {return 2}
    ;})

    .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.portfolio);
});

node.append("text")
    .attr("dx", 10)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("stroke", "white")
    .style("stroke-width", 2)
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 10)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name });
//End changed 

svg.append("arrow").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["source", "target"])
  .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 25)
    .attr("refY", 0)
    .attr("markerWidth", 8)
    .attr("markerHeight", 8)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5 L10,0 L0, -5")
    .style("stroke", "#4679BD")
    .style("opacity", "0.6");



//Now we are giving the SVGs co-ordinates - the force layout is generating the co-ordinates which this code is using to update the attributes of the SVG elements
force.on("tick", function () {



    link.attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });


    node.attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });    

    finalArray.forEach(function(d) {
          linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
          linkedByIndex[d.target.index + "," + d.source.index] = 1;
        });
});

    function neighboring(a, b) {
      return a.index == b.index || linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index];
    }


function mouseover(d) {
      d3.selectAll("path").style("stroke","red").style("stroke-width",1);
      d3.selectAll(".link").style("stroke","black");
      d3.selectAll(".link").transition().duration(500)
        .style("opacity", function(o) {
        return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : .1;
      });
      d3.selectAll(".link2").style("stroke","black");
      d3.selectAll(".link2").transition().duration(500)
        .style("opacity", function(o) {
        return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : .1;
      });
      d3.selectAll(".node").transition().duration(500)
        .style("opacity", function(o) {
           return neighboring(d, o) ? 1 : .1;
        });
}

function mouseout() {
    d3.selectAll("path").style("stroke","#4679BD").style("stroke-width",1);
    d3.selectAll(".link").style("stroke","grey");
    d3.selectAll(".link").transition().duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 1);
    d3.selectAll(".link2").style("stroke","green");
    d3.selectAll(".link2").transition().duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 1);
  d3.selectAll(".node").transition().duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 1);
}
/*
 src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js">
 type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/john-guerra/forceInABox/master/forceInABox.js">
 type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js">
*/
</script>
           </div>
        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why pointers change size along with the link width?

That's the normal behaviour of an SVG marker: the wider the stroke of the path, the larger the marker. According to the [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#MarkerElement), the default behaviour is:

> ‘markerWidth’, ‘markerHeight’ and the contents of the ‘marker’ represent values in a coordinate system which has a single unit equal the size in user units of the current **stroke width** (emphasis mine)

To prevent that, you have to use [`markerUnits = userSpaceOnUse`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#MarkerUnitsAttribute):

```
.attr("markerUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gnv1x84k/

(PS: I made some changes in your fiddle, which was not producing any arrow heads)

Comment: Thank you! I actually need to hide arrow heads in some cases. 
Another issue I noticed, is that it only counts number of connections (volume) from a to b, but not b to a. For example, a3-a4 link should be 1 px thicker as it has 4 connections. https://jsfiddle.net/Alexey_D3/xhx3L8jn/2/